# Define a grammar for language $L = \{a^{n}b^{*}c^{2n+1} \}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

could someone please help me define grammar for given language (or help me to improve mine): $L = \{a^{n}b^{*}c^{2n+1}  | n >= 1\}$

this is what I have so far, but it is not correct:
$$S → aSc$$
$$S → BC$$
$$B → bB$$
$$B → ε$$
$$C → cC$$
$$C → ε$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: 
$S \rightarrow Ac$ 
$A \rightarrow aBc^2$ 
$B \rightarrow aBc^2$ 
$B \rightarrow \epsilon$ 
$B \rightarrow Cb$ 
$C \rightarrow Cb$ 
$C \rightarrow \epsilon$